# read data as it is from excel in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I want to read data from excel and display it in gridview. The data in excel may be any format. For example : If I have 87.% in the excel, I am getting it as 0.875. I have to get it as it is, i.e., as 87.5. Is there any way to accomplish this without changing the actual excel file to be read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `.Text` of the cell rather than the `.Value` property.  Sample VBA will illustrate the difference:

```
Set c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 
c.Value = 1234.56
c.NumberFormat = "##0.00%" 
MsgBox c.Value 
MsgBox c.Text
```

Comment: very thank you for that. Its working. but I have got a new problem now. I want to display an excel file as it is in a grid. The data is displaying correctly but the merged cells are creating a problem. Is there any way to display an excel file as it is to gridview? Or using any other classes? Currently I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in .aspx.cs and gridview in .aspx. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SARATH: Please accept this answer and post another one relating to merged cells. That will provide an easier way for other users to see the response as well.

Comment: @SARATH: can you update your post with more specific details of your problem? Tell me what have you tried so far, so I can assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the data from Excel? Excel separates out data into two things, value and format. In your example the value is 0.875 and the format is 00%. You may be able to use the tool you are using to get the format, or to return the formatted value.

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Comment: @SARATH: In that case, the `NumberFormat` should contain `0%`, which you can use to manually set the outputted text.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380/) in Microsoft's forums